# jquery ui autocomplete, render <div> around <ul> results

Tags: jquery-ui

By default, jquery ui's autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) renders an <ul> around the search results. Is there any way to make it render a div tag before and after with a certain class added to them? Thanks

Comment: Because i want to put a certain layout on the box. Should look something like a speechbubble. I want 3 divs. The one in the middle should have a repeatable-y background and contain the <ul>. The other two divs are for top and bottom graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete').wrap('<div class="classname" />');
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. But what do i need to type to make it wrap it like this: `<div class="top"></div><div class="content"> $('.ui-autocomplete') here.. </div><div class="bot"></div>` Thanks in advance